# ¿Cómo programo paginador alfabético con php y MySQL?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, base-de-datos, paginación

Buenas tardes foro de **STACKOVERFLOW**, hoy les traigo un tema que me ha causado duda ya que estoy programando un paginador, pero quisiera hacer uno que me muestre en los enlaces las letras del abecedario en lugar de solo números.

A continuación les muestro mi código (funciona perfectamente), me gustaría que los enlaces de la parte inferior fueran letras y no números y así ver en la página los usuarios que empiecen con la letra del enlace:

```
<?php 

                    $CantidadMostrar=20;
                    //Conexion  al servidor mysql
                    $conetar = new mysqli('localhost', 'prueba', '123456', 'intranet_soporte_bitacora');
                    $conetar->set_charset("utf8");
                    if ($conetar->connect_errno) {
                        echo "Fallo al conectar a MySQL: (" . $conetar->connect_errno . ") " . $conetar->connect_error;
                    }else{
                                        // Validado de la variable GET
                        $compag=(int)(!isset($_GET['pag'])) ? 1 : $_GET['pag']; 
                        $TotalReg       =$conetar->query("SELECT * FROM empleados");
                        //Se divide la cantidad de registro de la BD con la cantidad a mostrar 
                        $TotalRegistro  =ceil($TotalReg->num_rows/$CantidadMostrar);
                        $consultavistas ="SELECT * FROM empleados ORDER BY usuario ASC LIMIT ".(($compag-1)*$CantidadMostrar)." , ".$CantidadMostrar;
                        $consulta=$conetar->query($consultavistas);
                             echo '<table class="consultas">
                                        <tr class="toptable">
                                            <td>ID Usuario</td>
                                            <td>Usuario</td>
                                            <td>Responsable</td>
                                            <td>Origen</td>
                                            <td>Eliminar</td>
                                        </tr>';                     

                        while ($lista=$consulta->fetch_row()) {
                             echo '<tr><td>'.$lista[0].'</td><td>'.$lista[3].'</td><td>'.$lista[2].'</td><td>'.$lista[8].'</td><td class="linkin"><a onclick="modificar('.$lista[0].'); return false;" ><i class="material-icons">edit</i>Modificar</a></td></tr>';
                        }
                            echo '</table>';
                            ?>
                            <script type="text/javascript">
                            function modificar(id){

                                swal({
                                  title: '¿Seguro qué Deseas Modificar este Usuario?',
                                  text: "¡Esta acción es irreversible!",
                                  type: 'warning',
                                  showCancelButton: true,
                                  confirmButtonColor: '#006633',
                                  cancelButtonColor: '#FF0000',
                                  confirmButtonText: '¡Sí, Quiero Modificarlo!',
                                  cancelButtonText: 'Cancelar'
                                }).then((result) => {
                                  if (result.value) {
                                        window.location="modificacion.php?id="+id;                                                  
                                    return true;
                                  } else {                                  
                                    return false;
                                  }
                                })
                            }</script>
                            <?php 

                        /*Sector de Paginacion */

                        //Operacion matematica para botón siguiente y atrás 
                        $IncrimentNum =(($compag +1)<=$TotalRegistro)?($compag +1):1;
                        $DecrementNum =(($compag -1))<1?1:($compag -1);

                        echo "<div class=\"pagina\"><ul ><li ><a href=\"?pag=".$DecrementNum."\">◀</a></li>";
                        //Se resta y suma con el numero de pag actual con el cantidad de 
                        //números  a mostrar
                         $Desde=$compag-(ceil($CantidadMostrar/2)-1);
                         $Hasta=$compag+(ceil($CantidadMostrar/2)-1);

                         //Se valida
                         $Desde=($Desde<1)?1: $Desde;
                         $Hasta=($Hasta<$CantidadMostrar)?$CantidadMostrar:$Hasta;
                         //Se muestra los números de paginas
                         for($i=$Desde; $i<=$Hasta;$i++){
                            //Se valida la paginacion total
                            //de registros
                            if($i<=$TotalRegistro){
                                //Validamos la pag activo
                              if($i==$compag){
                               echo "<li class=\"seleccionada\"><a href=\"?pag=".$i."\">".$i."</a></li>";
                              }else {
                                echo "<li><a href=\"?pag=".$i."\">".$i."</a></li>";
                              }             
                            }
                         }
                        echo "<li><a href=\"?pag=".$IncrimentNum."\">▶</a></li></ul></div>";

                    }
                ?>
```

[image: Así se ve mi tabla y funciona perfecto el paginador]

Espero que puedan ayudarme amigos :D

Comment: Entiendo lo que queres hacer. Ahora escribir las letras es lo mismo que tenes pero usando char, para transformar los numeros en letras (usando los ascii). eso trae problemas?

Comment: @gbianchi no amigo, no sé como hacerlo, por eso publico como programarlo, tienes idea de como hacerlo con la consulta de MySQL y php?

Comment: Para usar letras, tenes que cambiar varias partes de tu logica. Por ejemplo ya no importa cuantas paginas hay, si no si la letra tiene algun destino. Con char(number) transformas el codigo ascci a una letra.. ahi ya tenes el punto de partida.

Comment: revisa esto: https://miarroba.mforos.com/17451/1757323-paginacion-con-letras/

Comment: @gbianchi trataré de revisar como lo logro amigo

Comment: @Tegito123 gracias amigo, reviso el foro, saludos :D

Comment: @Tegito123 si hay una respuesta valida alli, porque no la agregas aca tambien?

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo un ejemplo, dado que me causo curiosidad como hacerlo espero y te sirva:

```
    <?php
     $host="localhost"; 
     $username="root"; 
     $password=""; 
     $db_name="intranet_soporte_bitacora"; 
     // conectando a mysql

     $conn=mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password) or die("error en la conexion"); 
     mysqli_select_db($conn,$db_name);
     if(isset($_GET['parametro'])){
       $parametro = mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['parametro']);
     }else{
      $get = '';
     }
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM empleados WHERE nombre LIKE '$parametro%' ORDER BY nombre asc LIMIT 15";
     $query = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

     echo "<table border='1' id='miTabla' width='100%'>
         <tr><th colspan='9' align='center'><h2>Empleados</h2></th></tr>
         <tr bgcolor='grey'>
             <th width='25%'>Nombre</th>
             <th width='25%'>Edad</th>
             <th width='25%'>Email</th>
         </tr>";
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
        {
          echo "<tr>";
          echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['nombre']. "</td>";
          echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['edad']. "</td>";
          echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['email'] . "</td>";
          echo "</tr>";
        }
     echo "</table>";
     mysqli_close($conn);   
?>
<?php
$alfabeto = range('A', 'Z');
 foreach ($alfabeto as $key) {?>
<a href="donde_recibo.php?parametro=<?php  echo $key  ?>"><?php echo $key ?></a>
<?php }?>
```

es un pequeño ejemplo como podrias hacerlo existen multiples formas de hacerlo...espero y te sirva !!